# How to run Processing qgis:extractbylocation?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I try to use the processing `'qgis:extractbylocation'` in QGIS 2.8.2 from the QGIS algorithm provider.

```
import processing
# import the layers by a given uri
inputlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uriTr.uri(), "inputlayer", "postgres")
intersectlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uriOSM.uri(), "intersectlayer", "postgres")

# initialize a predicate instance
pred_intersects = processing.core.parameters.ParameterGeometryPredicate(enabledPredicates = 'intersects')
# run the processing
processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', inputlayer, intersectlayer, pred_intersects, None)
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "~/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 71, in runalg
        alg = Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args)
    File "~/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 317, in runAlgorithm
        if not param.setValue(args[i]):
    File "~/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 829, in setValue
        elif len(value) == 0:
AttributeError: ParameterGeometryPredicate instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

The algorithm needs the following inputs

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:extractbylocation")
     ALGORITHM: Extract by location
     INPUT <ParameterVector>
     INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
     PREDICATE <ParameterGeometryPredicate>
     OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

ParameterGeometryPredicate is described here: https://fossies.org/dox/qgis-2.8.2/classprocessing_1_1core_1_1parameters_1_1ParameterGeometryPredicate.html

How do I need to initialize a correct instance of the ParameterGeometryPredicate class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate is `u'intersects'`. For more than one predicate use an array like  `"[u'within',u'intersects']"`

The full command is

```
processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', inputlayer, intersectlayer, u'intersects', None)
```

The possible arguments for the predicates are:

```
[u'disjoint',u'intersects',u'contains',u'equals',u'touches',u'overlaps',u'within',u'crosses']
```

The similar algorithm `selectbylocation` is used like

```
processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', inputlayer, intersectlayer, u'intersects', 0)
```

Comment: Why do I need to mark it as an Unicode string? And why isn't this necessary for the GUI?

Comment: Because the encoding of the GUI is unicode

Answer (score 3):

Run the "*Extract by location*" command of the Toolbox and examine the last line of the `../.qgis2/processing/processing.log` file (that records all the commands executed)

```
ALGORITHM|Sun Jun 14 2015 17:34:39|
processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation","/Users/Shared/result.shp","/Users/Shared/input.shp","['intersects']",None)
```

The predicate is simply **"['intersects']"**

Comment: This does not work. In the script `/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByLocation.py` there is the loop `for predicate in predicates:` This loop just iterates over the single chars of **"['intersects']"**. You won't get an error, but no selected features either.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
['intersects']
```