# Using qgis:selectbylocation in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, select-by-location, point-in-polygon, spatial-query

I am trying to use the processing toolbox to perform a spatial query (points in polygon). I am not sure how to use the tool and I keep getting this Error:

> Wrong number of parameters.

Here is my script:

```py
polygon_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\mitte.shp"
points_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\punkte.shp"

polygon = QgsVectorLayer(polygon_path, 'Mitte', 'ogr')
points = QgsVectorLayer(points_path, 'Berlin Punkte', 'ogr')

processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', points, polygon, False, False, False, 0)
```

I used the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html), which indicates that I have to use **6** parameters.

However, if I call `alghelp` the following is returned, indicating **5** parameters:

```
ALGORITHM: Select by location
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
    PREDICATE <ParameterGeometryPredicate>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>


METHOD(Aktuelle Auswahl ändern mit)
    0 - creating new selection
    1 - adding to current selection
    2 - removing from current selection
```

Either way I am not getting it to run correctly.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to run Processing qgis:extractbylocation?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150887/how-to-run-processing-qgisextractbylocation)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used this code:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', layers[0], layers[1], u'within', 0)
```

with this situation:

[image]

and it worked:

[image]

**Updating for QGIS 3:**

Following code works in QGIS 3.20 (Odense):

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

parameters = { 'INPUT' : layers[0], 
               'INTERSECT' : layers[1], 
               'METHOD' : 0, 
               'PREDICATE' : [0] }

processing.run('qgis:selectbylocation', parameters )
```

I tried it out as it can be observed in following picture.

[image]

Comment: Incredible! This will be a heavily upvoted answer, as it is the only example on the entire web that actually works ;-)

Comment: I still can't figure out how to read the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html). It looks like there should be two parameters in between layers[1] and 0. But it won't run if you go about it that way... is it just wrong or do I not know how to read it?

Comment: I used this documentation (for qgis 2.8; not for qgis 2.6): https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html