# Performing a Spatial Query in a loop in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, select-by-location, spatial-query, qgis-2.10

What I am trying to do: *loop* through a point shapefile and select each point that falls *into* a polygon.

The following code is inspired by a spatial query example I found in a book:

```
mitte_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\mitte.shp"
punkte_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\punkte.shp"

polygon = QgsVectorLayer(mitte_path, 'Mitte', 'ogr')
points = QgsVectorLayer(punkte_path, 'Berlin Punkte', 'ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(polygon)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(points)

polyFeatures = polygon.getFeatures()

pointsCount = 0

for poly_feat in polyFeatures:
    polyGeom = poly_feat.geometry()
    pointFeatures = points.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(polyGeom.boundingBox()))
    for point_feat in pointFeatures:
        points.select(point_feat.id())
        pointsCount += 1

print 'Total:',pointsCount
```

This works, and it does select datasets, but the problem is that it selects *by bounding box*, hence obviously returning points I am not interested in:

[image]

How could I go about only returning points *within* the polygon without using [qgis:selectbylocation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168689/how-to-use-qgisselectbylocation-in-pyqgis)?

I have tried using the **within()** and **intersects()** methods, but as I was not getting them to work, I resorted to the code above. But perhaps they're the key after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some advice from a workmate I finally got it to work using within().

*General logic*

1. get features of polygon(s)
2. get features of points
3. loop through each feature from polygon file, and for each:

   - get geometry
   - loop through all points

     - get geometry of single point
     - test if geometry is within geometry of polygon

Here is the code:

```
mitte_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\mitte.shp"
punkte_path = r"D:\PythonTesting\SelectByLocation\punkte.shp"

poly = QgsVectorLayer(mitte_path, 'Mitte', 'ogr')
points = QgsVectorLayer(punkte_path, 'Berlin Punkte', 'ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(poly)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(points)

polyFeatures = poly.getFeatures()
pointFeatures = points.getFeatures()

pointCounter = 0

for polyfeat in polyFeatures:
    polyGeom = polyfeat.geometry()
    for pointFeat in pointFeatures:
        pointGeom = pointFeat.geometry()
        if pointGeom.within(polyGeom):
            pointCounter += 1
            points.select(pointFeat.id())

print 'Total',pointCounter
```

This would also work with **intersects()** instead of **within()**. When using points it *does not matter* which one you would use, as they will both return the same result.
When checking for lines/polygons, however, it can make an important difference: within() returns objects that are *entirely* within, whereas intersects() retuns objects that are entirely within **and** that are *partly* within (i.e. that *intersect* with the feature, as the name indicates).

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution. It works only if you have one polygons, otherwise only the points within the first polygon will be selected

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a special function (as "Ray Casting"), everything is in PyQGIS (**contains()** in [PyQGIS Geometry Handling](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html))

```
polygons = [feature for feature in polygons.getFeatures()]
points = [feature for feature in points.getFeatures()]
for pt in points: 
     point = pt.geometry() # only and not pt.geometry().asPolygon() 
     for pol in polygons:
        poly = pol.geometry()
        if poly.contains(point):
             print "ok"
```

or in one line

```
 polygons = [feature for feature in polygons.getFeatures()]
 points = [feature for feature in points.getFeatures()]
 resulting = [pt for pt in points for poly in polygons if poly.geometry().contains(pt.geometry())]
 print len(resulting)
 ...
```

You can also directly use

```
[pt.geometry().asPoint() for pt in points for poly in polygons if poly.geometry().contains(pt.geometry())]
```

The problem here is that you must iterate through all the geometries (polygons and points). It is more interesting to use a bounding spatial index : you iterate only through the geometries which have a chance to intersect with your current geometry ('filter', look at [How to efficiently access the features returned by QgsSpatialIndex?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130457))

Comment: Also see http://nathanw.net/2013/01/04/using-a-qgis-spatial-index-to-speed-up-your-code/

Comment: @gene, can i ask a question, is there anyway to avoid using two for loops, in large datasets this is not good for complexity reasons?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "Ray Casting" [algorithm](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/01/point-in-polygon.html) that I have slightly adapted for using with PyQGIS:

```
def point_in_poly(point,poly):
    x = point.x()
    y = point.y()

    n = len(poly)
    inside = False

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

    return inside

## Test
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

#For polygon 
polygon = [feature.geometry().asPolygon() 
            for feature in layers[1].getFeatures()]

points = [feat.geometry().asPoint() 
           for feat in layers[0].getFeatures()]

## Call the function with the points and the polygon
count = [0]*(layers[1].featureCount())

for point in points:
    i = 0
    for feat in polygon:
        if point_in_poly(point, feat[0]) == True:
            count[i] += 1
        i += 1

print count
```

Applied to this situation:

[image]

the result, at the Python Console, was:

```
[2, 2]
```

It worked.

**Editing Note:**

Code with the more concise proposal of **gene**:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = mapcanvas.layers()

count = [0]*(layers[1].featureCount())

polygon = [feature
           for feature in layers[1].getFeatures()]

points = [feature
          for feature in layers[0].getFeatures()]

for point in points:

    i = 0

    geo_point = point.geometry()

    for pol in polygon:
        geo_pol = pol.geometry()

        if geo_pol.contains(geo_point):
            count[i] += 1
        i += 1

print count
```

Comment: Great reference and great answer! I will mark the one I just posted, however, as the solution, as it is a little easier to implement. You should be rewarded with a lot of upvotes though. +1 from me, for sure.

Comment: You don't need to specify `if geo_pol.contains(geo_point) == True:` because it is implicit in `if geo_pol.contains(geo_point)` (always True)