# Python: Point in polygon, boundary and vertex check (ray casting)

Tags: python, point-in-polygon, iterator, function

So I have written some code to check whether a point [(x,y)] lies within a polygon [(x,y), (x,y), (x,y), (x,y)] but the code fails if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex, I need this to be classed as lying within the polygon. This is the code:

```
def areasign(poly):
    sumarea = 0
    for i in range(0, len(poly)-1):
        xi = poly[i][0]
        yi = poly[i][1]
        xj = poly[i+1][0]
        yj = poly[i+1][1]
        sumarea = sumarea + ((xi*yj)-(yi*xj))

    if sumarea == 0: return 0
    if sumarea < 0:  return -1
    if sumarea > 0:  return 1

def lineintersection(xy, ij):
    xyi = []
    xyj = []
    ijx = []
    ijy = []
    xyi.extend(xy)
    xyj.extend(xy)
    xyi.append(ij[0])
    xyj.append(ij[1])
    xyi.append(xy[0])
    xyj.append(xy[0])
    ijx.extend(ij)
    ijy.extend(ij)
    ijx.append(xy[0])
    ijy.append(xy[1])
    ijx.append(ij[0])
    ijy.append(ij[0])
    a = areasign(xyi)
    b = areasign(xyj)
    c = areasign(ijx)
    d = areasign(ijy)
    if (a!= b) and (c!=d):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def openpointfile(fname):
    p = []
    f = open(fname)
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('POINT(', '')
        line = line.replace(')', '')
        vals = line.split(' ')
        res = map(float, vals)
        ctuple = tuple(res)
        p.append(ctuple)
        print ctuple
    f.close()
    return p

points =         openpointfile('C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Informatics/Data/Point_On_Line.txt')

def openpolygonfile(fname):
    p = []
    f = open(fname)
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('POLYGON((', '')
        line = line.replace('))', '')
        s = line.split(',')
        poly = []
        for coord in s:
            vals = coord.split(' ')
            res = map(float, vals)
            ctuple = tuple(res)
            poly.append(ctuple)
        p.append(poly)      
    f.close()
    return p

polys = openpolygonfile('C:/Users/Dan/Documents/Informatics/Data/Polygon_On_Line.txt')

def pointinpoly(points, polys):
    infinity = tuple([100000000.0, 100000010.0])
    sum = 0
    testline = (points, infinity)
    for i in range(0, len(poly)-1):
        start = poly[i]
        end = poly[i+1]
        line = (start, end)
        l = lineintersection(line, testline)
        if l == True:
            sum = sum + 1
    if sum % 2 == 0:
        return  False
    else:
        return True

pointcount = 0
for point in points:
    pointcount = pointcount + 1
    polycount = 0
    for poly in polys:
        polycount = polycount + 1
        l = pointinpoly(point, poly)
        res = 'Point ' + str(pointcount) + ' lies within Polygon ' + str(polycount) + ' = ' + str(l)
        print l
        print (res)
```

Like i said before this doesnt work if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex, i have this function that i found on here that seems to work but i can't find a way to get it my files into the correct format for the function and to get it to iterate oer a list of polygons.

```
def point_in_poly(x,y,poly):

   # check if point is a vertex
   if (x,y) in poly: return "IN"

   # check if point is on a boundary
   for i in range(len(poly)):
      p1 = None
      p2 = None
      if i==0:
         p1 = poly[0]
         p2 = poly[1]
      else:
         p1 = poly[i-1]
         p2 = poly[i]
      if p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[1] == y and x > min(p1[0], p2[0]) and x < max(p1[0], p2[0]):
         return "IN"

   n = len(poly)
   inside = False

   p1x,p1y = poly[0]
   for i in range(n+1):
      p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
      if y > min(p1y,p2y):
         if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
               if p1y != p2y:
                  xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
               if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                  inside = not inside
      p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

   if inside: return "IN"
   else: return "OUT"
```

Any help on how to build that function into my existing code or any help on a new function that could be used to check if the point lies on the boundary of a polygon or on a vertex

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)

Comment: This is for a project of mine, so I cant use libraries because i am using shapely to test my code. My other thoughts were to use matplotlib and use paths but without trying to reinvent the wheel i'm just trying to use basic principles and put them into code :) any thoughts on doing it without shapely ?

Comment: [Point in Polygon 2: Walking the line](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/08/point-in-polygon-2-on-line.html) for example but there are others

Comment: or [Computational Geometry in Python: From Theory to Application](http://www.toptal.com/python/computational-geometry-in-python-from-theory-to-implementation)

Comment: and for the matplotlib paths use [descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah that's the function i mention in the second half of my post, it works great but i am struggling to get it to iterate over my polygons as they are wkt and in a .txt file.

Comment: Why not add, in addition to your tests, a simple block that iterates over every vertex in the polygon and checks to see if the coordinates match the point in question? Also, again iterate over every vertex, mathematically define the line segment to the next (or last) vertex, and check mathematically whether the point in question lies on that line? The only special case to handle there is a perfectly vertical line (since it has infinite slope).

Comment: Cheers for looking at this ! I get how to do that mathematically but I cant visualise a way to put that into code ? Sorry i'm such a novice, I'm just keen to learn this as I know how helpful coding will be.

Comment: Here is [an answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168703/23263) mentioning Ray Casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> whether a point [(x,y)] lies within a polygon [(x,y), (x,y), (x,y), (x,y)] but the code fails if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex

You need to understand the topologic rules:

- From [Quirks of the "Contains" Spatial Predicate](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.be/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html)

> Polygons do not contain their boundary (Geometry A contains Geometry B if no points of B lie in the exterior of A, and at least one point of the interior of B lies in the interior of A)

- and from the [Shapely User Manual: Binary Predicates](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates))

> Contains Returns True if the object’s interior contains the boundary and interior of the other object and their boundaries do not touch at all.

**Thus, it is normal that your code fails if the point lies on a boundary or a vertex**

A polygon, its LinearRing (boundary) and a vertex point

[image]

1) Control of the predicates with the [Java Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) (same for polygon and a vertex point)

[image]

2) Control with [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html)

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
# boundary of the polygon = LinearRing
linearring = LinearRing(list(polygon.exterior.coords))
print linearring
LINEARRING (0 0, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0)
# contains
polygon.contains(linearring)
False
# a vertex 
point = Point(1,1)
polygon.contains(point)
False
```

But

```
polygon.touches(linearring)
True
polygon.touches(point)
True
polygon.intersect(linearring)
True
polygon.intersect(point)
True
```

And

```
linearring.contains(point)
True
```