# Error in qgis:selectbylocation python processing method

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-location

I am having trouble with my code for selecting all points within a buffer layer, with the error given below. I am using this documentation as reference for the field formats:
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html . I also tried the solution posted here [How to use qgis:selectbylocation in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168689/how-to-use-qgisselectbylocation-in-pyqgis) . Is there something that I'm missing?

```
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation", 
                  "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp",
                  "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Blast_Files/Blast_buffers/blast_induced_buff.shp", 
                  False, 
                  False, 
                  False, 
                  0)

Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Select by location
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
    PREDICATE <ParameterGeometryPredicate>
    PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

METHOD(Modify current selection by)
    0 - creating new selection
    1 - adding to current selection
    2 - removing from current selection

EDIT: I am using QGIS 2.14, and have updated my code as follows (with the error below). Following documentation posted here: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools.html?highlight=selectbylocation

```
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation", 
                  "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp", 
                  "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Blast_Files/Blast_buffers/blast_induced_buff.shp", 
                  'within', 
                  0)

Error: Wrong number of parameters
ALGORITHM: Select by location
    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    INTERSECT <ParameterVector>
    PREDICATE <ParameterGeometryPredicate>
    PRECISION <ParameterNumber>
    METHOD <ParameterSelection>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the Processing algorithm from QGIS GUI and then go to `Processing -> History` to see how to run the algorithm in QGIS Python Console.

```
processing.runalg("qgis:selectbylocation", 
    "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/qgis/moment_all.shp", 
    "/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Blast_Files/Blast_buffers/blast_induced_buff.shp", 
    ['within'], 
    0, 
    0)
```

Note that:

- PREDICATE parameter should be passed as a Python array of strings: `['within']` instead of `'within'`.
- You're missing the second to last parameter called PRECISION, which in the command above is 0. Of course, you can adjust it according to your scenario.

Comment: These 2 additions resolved my issue- thank you! The code in your answer worked perfectly. I didn't know about the processing -> history option; I'll certainly be using this more often :)

Comment: You're welcome. Right, that's a very handy log.